# удаление дубля строк с условием

Tags: python

Суть. Имеем файл с содержимым:

```
type sysfs_batt_SC30, fs_type, sysfs_type;
type sysfs_devinfo, fs_type, sysfs_type;
type panel_crash_counter_file, file_type;
type panel_timeout_counter_file, file_type;
type sysfs_leds, fs_type, sysfs_type;
type sysfs_leds, fs_type, sysfs_type;
type sysfs_leds, fs_type, sysfs_type;
type sysfs_leds, fs_type, sysfs_type;
```

Нужно удалить дублирование строк, но чтобы одна осталась, т.е было

```
type sysfs_leds, fs_type, sysfs_type;
type sysfs_leds, fs_type, sysfs_type;
type sysfs_leds, fs_type, sysfs_type;
type sysfs_leds, fs_type, sysfs_type;
```

а стало

```
type sysfs_leds, fs_type, sysfs_type;
```

и тому подобное.

Пробовал через

```
File = open('file.te', 'r')
str_list = []
for i in File.readlines():
    if i not in str_list:
        str_list.append(i)
File.close()
File = open('file.te', 'w')
for j in str_list:
    File.write(j)
```

но оно работает не так как положено, а просто убирает ВСЕ строки, которые продублированы. Как этот алгоритм до ума довести?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ответ на ваш предыдущий вопрос достаточно добавить пару фигурных скобок, чтобы он стал ответом и на этот вопрос тоже:

```
lines = []
with open('file.txt') as fh:
    lines = fh.readlines()

with open('file.txt', 'w') as fh:
    fh.writelines({i for i in lines if '_exec' not in i})
```

А если править ваш вариант, то замените `str_list = []` на `str_list = set()`.

Comment: Если заменить то получится AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Замените ещё `str_list.append(i)` на `str_list.add(i)`. Или не заменяйте `str_list = []`, а замените `for j in str_list` на `for j in set(str_list)`.

Answer (score 1):

Пробуйте еще и так :

```
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('file.txt') as file:
    uniq = OrderedDict.fromkeys(file)
with open('file2.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(uniq)
```